# Split character vector values by fixed delimiter - return data frame with one row for each vector value

Tags: r, dataframe, split

The delimiter is present in all vector values, and only once, thus each vector value should result in exactly one pair and the result should be a two column data frame.

I am not unhappy about my solution, but wondered if there might be cool functions around that make this easier. Open for any package, but base R preferred.

```r
test <- rep("a,b", 5)

# expected result
data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, strsplit(test, ","))))
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  a  b
#> 2  a  b
#> 3  a  b
#> 4  a  b
#> 5  a  b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate()`.

```
test <- data.frame(x = rep("a,b", 5))
separate(test,x, c("X1","X2"))
#>   X1 X2
#> 1  a  b
#> 2  a  b
#> 3  a  b
#> 4  a  b
#> 5  a  b
```

Comment: very clever! Hah, I haven't thought of first converting the vector into a data frame

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(test) %>%
  extract(col = test, 
          into = c("X1", "X2"),
          regex = "(.),(.)")
 X1 X2
1 a  b
2 a  b
3 a  b
4 a  b
5 a  b
```

Data:

```
test <- rep("a,b", 5)
```